# how can i add multiple images to custom meta from front end wordpress without plugin

Tags: image, upload

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535068/wordpress-multiple-images-upload-via-front-end-to-a-custom-post-types-post-met
the above link, here shows single image upload system to custom field from front end. but i need multiple . hepl please...

Answer (score 1):

There is a link given in the comment of one of the answers to the sample question you have posted try that one out. https://gist.github.com/daltonrooney/1737887

Comment: Thank you for your value able reply. appriciated . multiple images has been uploaded on media library. but those images are not save to the meta field. i need also that, uploaded images will be save to multiple meta field with uploading like a title, description & featured image etc. See those link please 1.  http://prnt.sc/avq53t
2. http://prnt.sc/avq89z